# Using LinkedIn for social login to salesforce

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, single-sign-on, oauth2, authentication

so i have been looking for solutions all over the web to try and find the solution to this simple question: how do i use linkedin as a social login method for any salesforce app/portal/community i create?

it seems that i can only use Janrain as an auth provider but then Janrain requires me to contact their sales department, get setup with them and they do some parts of the integration.

I know that Linkedin has a REST / Javascript API login solution but was looking for something like SAML / OAuth2.

Is there any developer solution that i could implement for login and registration without requiring a third party to step in for part of the maintenance / setup? i just need to know what is the most effective way of doing this and possibly if anyone can direct me to some documentation sources so i can piece this all together.

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble setting this up myself, but I believe it can be set up using the Open ID Connect as the Auth Provider type.

Comment: Thanks but i checked and could not find any documentation confirming that at the time i posted this question.